# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND , it will not load the img in html

Tags: html, image, resources, load

I started building a simple webpage, and I finished adding my HTML elements, the last thing to add were pictures in the img tag.

```
<section>
    <div><img src="hand-made.png"></div>
```

this is the code I wrote, and when I refresh the page image is broken and I get **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**. I have tried moving it to different files, I tried changing it in the console, I tested with placeholder.it and that works.Idk what to do..

Comment: Please show the code you used to "tested with placeholder".

Comment: have you tried adding a closing tag for <section> like </section>?

Comment: Your image path is looking for the image in the same directory as your html file. Is the image in the same directory?

Comment: http://placehold.it/300x100  i used this to see . if this was broken too that i would know its a bigger problem

Comment: the section is closed , the code is long so i didnt wanna put the whole thing in

Comment: @MichaelvE it is in the same directory

Comment: @MichaelvE all the images and my index.html and style-sheet.css are in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

You either do not have a file called `hand-made.png` in **the same folder** as your script, or your browser has cached the invalid reference. First, ensure that you have uploaded the image to the same folder as your index file.

If the image you are trying to reference is in a different folder, you can use:

- Relative links (`../images/hand-made.png`) to shift up folders
- Root-relate links (`/images/hand-made.png`) to reference the file from the root of your website
- Absolute links (`https://www.website.com/images/hand-made.png`) to reference the filke in absolute relation to your site structure.

If you are still unable to load the file, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +  <kbd>R</kbd> to forcibly clear the cache and refresh the page.

Comment: The `hand-mage.png` is in the same folder as my index i have tryed relative link , root-relate links , and the crtl+shift+r , getting errors on all of them. however with the absolute link images work if i take them directly from a website.

Comment: this is a noob question , is there any difference if the image comes from my folder or direcrly from some other website?